# Saxon Xslt Processor Error

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

In my .net application i am trying process an xml using saxon xslt, the xslt version is 2.0.
When the data is large i am getting the following error.

[net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException] = {"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."}

Any ideas what it is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The message you've provided suggests to me that the XML document you're attempting to transform (or perhaps the XSLT stylesheet) is not well-formed XML.  Can you read the XML document (and the stylesheet) using an XML parser?